# Mark unbalanced quotes in csquote

Tags: errors, csquotes, quotation

I'm using `csquotes` to type plain quotes using `\MakeOuterQuotes`.
Whenever it encounters an unbalanced quote it throws an error message (rightly so!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} %autostyle=true important for biblatex-chicago
     \MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
A balanced "quote" 
and an unbalanced" one. 
\end{document}
```

Is there a way, though, instead of stopping the typesetting to let me fix the problem right away, to have it print a warning in the PDF instead?  Like an oversized red exclamation mark or something?

I'd prefer to identify the problems on the printout when proofreading, as opposed to sit waiting and going back to the source every time to fix it.

Comment: Not really. In some cases csquotes can detect a problem (and it will then try to print a error mark if you continue the compilation. But try e.g. `{and an unbalanced" one.}`: you get a low level tex error directly.

Comment: The issue is also that `csquotes` can't really know where your quotation mark is missing. Some errors related to balance checking are only raised at the end of the the document and LaTeX doesn't really do back-tracking.